# Podio API csv query function depreciated

Tags: podio

Hi folks I just want to ask if the query call below for PODIO API is already or if  it will be depreciated soon? I'm asking because I'm using it on 3rd party Dashboarding toool

https://api.podio.com/item/app//csv

I cannot see any documentation for it other than for xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about item export (https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/export-items-4235696) then only supported formats are xls and xlsx.